# Pyspark:-Get the row values of a huge file(1gb) of any type for which the column values are 'False' without OOM error

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

when i try to collect the row values from a "Row_id"(custom created column) that contains integer values from 1 to (length of dataframe), according to a condition(columns with boolean false values), OOM error occurs only if the size of the file is huge. The below code works for a file having 10 rows and 5 columns but the same code fails to process the huge files.

```
listt_append=[]
        for z in range(len(dff_schema)):
            listt=[]
            for x in range(len(dff_schema[z].collect())):
                for y in range(len(dff_schema[z].collect()[x])):
                    if dff_schema[z].collect()[x][y]==False:
                        listt=listt+[dff_schema[z].collect()[x][-1]]
            listt_append.append(list(set(listt)))
```

I am using system with 16gb ram and i5 processor.

Comment: is there any ambiguity in the question? Please raise.

Comment: not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).